# regular expression search replace in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a lot of php files that must be changed, and I decided to use Sublime for it.
Now I want to change lines like

```
<td width="17%" class="listhdrr"><?=gettext("SOME TEXT");?></td>
```

to

```
<th><?=gettext("SOME TEXT");?></th>
```

I used

```
<td width="\d+%" class="listhdrr"><\?=gettext\("[A-Za-z\s+]+"\);\?></td>
```

regular expression. I don't need width of table's column but I want **SOME TEXT** in example.

My Replace expression was

```
<th><?=gettext("$1");?></th>  OR <th><?=gettext("\1");?></th>
```

that doesn't work for replace **SOME TEXT** Part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following;

```
<td width="\d+%" class="listhdrr"><\?=gettext\("(.+)"\);\?><\/td>
```

And use this for the substitution;

```
<th><?=gettext("$1");?></th>
```

To make use of the $1 in the match you need the brackets around the area you want to catch;

gettext("**(.+)**")

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rK6aD3/2)